# css icons that you can click anywhere and any size browser

Tags: html, css

i have 3 clickable icons im trying to make clickable no matter the size of the webpage they are clickable in full screen but when i make the screen smaller they are no longer clickable .. here is my codes

html code

```
<a class="button twitter nohide" href="https://twitter.com/Example" target="_blank"></a>
<a class="button off nohide" href="http://exampleid=12155487" target="_blank">
</a><a class="button amazon-link nohide" href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/Example/ref=topnav_lists_1" target="_blank"></a>
```

css code

```
a.button {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

a.button.amazon-link {
  width:250px;
  height:87px;
  background:url(http://oi57.tinypic.com/24php2p.jpg);
  top:0;
  left:730px;
}

a.button.twitter {
  width:250px;
  height:87px;
  background:url(http://oi58.tinypic.com/2n21w20.jpg);
  top:100px;
  left:730px;
}

a.button.offtip {
  width:250px;
  height:89px;
  background:url(http://oi59.tinypic.com/29c7v4i.jpg);
  top:0;
  left:470px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and see what you get

```
a.button {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
}

a.button.amazon-link {
  width:250px;
  height:87px;
  background:url(http://oi57.tinypic.com/24php2p.jpg);
  top:0;
  left:730px;
}

a.button.twitter-link {
  width:250px;
  height:87px;
  background:url(http://oi58.tinypic.com/2n21w20.jpg);
  top:0;
  left:210px;
}

a.button.offtip-link {
  width:250px;
  height:89px;
  background:url(http://oi59.tinypic.com/29c7v4i.jpg);
  top:0;
  left:470px;
}  

#buttons.resize {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a span element in an address will make something like a button that can be clicked anywhere in its rectangular area. Just control the size of the span because they are 0 width and 0 height by default, when they have no text inside.

```
<a class="button twitter nohide" href="https://twitter.com/Example" target="_blank">
    <span>
       This is my link.
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: ok well i figured out why it wasn't working when the page was smaller, i changed the position of the icons and they work no matter what size the browser is if its in the certain position , but if i move the icons further left on the browser then they are no longer clickable in that area only if they are far right of the browser ? any ideals ?

Comment: it might be silly but... some transparent elements might be blocking them. like a div or something.

Comment: true that .. appreciate it

Comment: <span>
<a class="button twitter nohide" href="https://twitter.com/example" target="_blank"></a>
<a class="button offtip nohide" href="https:/example/php/tip.php?request=tip&broadcaster_id=12155487" target="_blank"></a>
<a class="button amazon-link nohide" href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/example/ref=topnav_lists_1" target="_blank"></a>
</span>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><div></div>

Comment: you think it might be that div ? because i gotta use that to lower my other stuff i have , how you think i can fix it ?

Comment: doing inspect element on the unclickable link will confirm if it really is blocked by a div or something. in chrome, right-click on it and select "inspect element". a small box will appear displaying the html of your page. a portion of it will be highlighted. if the highlighted text is not your address, then it really is being blocked. this usually happens because of absolute positioning.